# Nhibernate mapping, join only brings back the first value in the joined table

Tags: nhibernate, ibm-midrange

I am trying to retrieve the plant name for some parts. I usually use entity framework but I am working with the AS400 and Entity Framework was not an option for AS00. I am getting only the first value found in the join. Parts with the same id can be made in different plants.

Actual Data
**Part Table    PartDetails Table**

- partid-1234, plant4
- partid-1234, plant5
- partid-1234, plant6

What the query returns
**Part Table    PartDetails Table**

- partid-1234, plant4
- partid-1234, plant4
- partid-1234, plant4

```
 <class name="Part" table="DCSCIM" dynamic-update="false">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="Id" column="ITMID" type="String">
      <generator class="uuid.string"/>
    </id>
    <property name="ITMDESC"/>
    <property name="ALTDESC"/>
    <property name="DTECRT"/>
    <join table="DMFPSMR">
      <key column="ITMID"/>
      <property name="PLT" column="PLT" type="String" length="100" />
    </join>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: What's your question? Which query do you execute? Why do you dislike vowels? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using collections, not `join`. I suggest you read the docs: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up joining the data n the repository instead of the mapping file with Linq.